# How to add a classname/id to React-Bootstrap Component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

Suppose we are using Row from React-Bootstrap... How do we style it without using a wrapper or inner element:

```
<Row>
  <div className='some-style'>
   ...
</Row>
```

Ideally, we could just do:

```
<Row className='some-style'> 
  ...
</Row>
```

But this doesn't work and I'd presume it's because `React-Bootstrap` does not know where the `className` goes within the `<Row>` component (it should just style the `<div>` that has the row styles).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Row.js#L23) for the component you can see that it uses the `className` prop passed to it to combine with the `row` class to get the resulting set of classes (`<Row className="aaa bbb"...` works).Also, if you provide the `id` prop like `<Row id="444" ...` it will actually set the id attribute for the element.

Comment: For some reason,  I thought Row and Col couldn't be styled like this. I think there have been other components where I faced this issue, will update if I come across it in the future

Answer (score 22):

The first way is to use props:

```
<Row id = "someRandomID">
```

Then in the definition, you may use:

```
const Row = props  => {
    <div id = {props.id}> something </div>
}
```

The same could be done with class, replacing `id` with `className` in the above example.

---

You might as well use `react-html-id`, that is an npm package.
This is an npm package that allows you to use unique html IDs for components without any dependencies on other libraries.

Ref: [react-html-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-id)

Answer (score 0):

You can add className to a React component like this:

```
    import React from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  
  const additionalClassName = 'another-class'; // Define the additional class name

  return (
    <div className={`my-class ${additionalClassName}`}>
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```