# How do I adjust the size of a column in React/Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
<div className={"col-7 name"}>&thinsp;</div>
```

When this loads into my page, the column is too big. I want to make it more narrow, and if possible, I want to apply an attribute directly inside the div.

What attributes can I add to col-7 name and what is the proper way to do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486660/how-to-add-a-classname-id-to-react-bootstrap-component

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap's grid system uses 12 columns per row. You specify the column width using the syntax `className='col-*'`.

Just change the `*` to the number of columns out of 12 you would like. For example, a div with `className='col-6'` will be half the width of a div with `className='col-12'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `bootstrap`

total column is 12, so you can use `col-12`

example:

1. `col-8` for 1 columns, `col-4` for 1 columns
2. `col-4` for 3 columns
3. `col-6` for 2 columns

you can try to take a look from their documentation

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/